# OpenGL - Placing a model in world space after drawing in camera space?

Tags: c++, opengl, camera

Is there a way in OpenGL to draw an object at camera space and have it stay at that position in world space once you move away?

I want to walk away from the bullet and have it stay in world space, rather than being in camera space and attached to the camera where-ever I go.

Is there a way to do this, or am I doing this wrong? I don't think that I can just draw the object in world space because I could be facing any direction.
Thanks.

Comment: Place the object in world space and draw it as you draw any other world space object.  Your gun also should be in world space. So just just displace the bullet in the direction the gun is facing (give it position and velocity) and that's it.

Comment: If I draw the bullet in world space (i.e. just give it an x, y and z value), then it'll work fine when facing forward, but say I turn right 90 degrees, then the bullet is still drawn in the same place.

Comment: Not sure if I understand you.  Turning (moving the camera in any direction) should have no effect on the relative position of objects in world space.  If it does then that is your real problem.

Comment: Well as far as I understand it, drawing in world space just means placing an object in the world at a certain location, and doesn't take into account where your camera is or which direction it's facing. Drawing in camera space does take those into account. Is that wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bullet is nothing different from any object in your world. What makes an object difference from other is its coordinates **in the same space**.

Having an object in camera coordinates means that you can avoid the multiplication by "Model" and "View" matrices, and use only "Projection" matrix.

If you have the bullet in camera coordinates you can get its world coordinates by multiplying them by the inverse of the "View * Model" matrix.

Let's say you set the **bullet relative to the camera** with your code:

```
glm::mat4 BulletRotationMatrix = glm::toMat4(bulletRotation);
// Offset so that it appears after the barrel of the gun
glm::mat4 BulletTranslationMatrix = translate(mat4(), glm::vec3(0.35, 0, -3));
glm::mat4 BulletScaleMatrix = scale(mat4(), glm::vec3(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f));
glm::mat4 ModelMatrix = BulletTranslationMatrix * BulletRotationMatrix * BulletScaleMatrix;
glm::mat4 MVP = ProjectionMatrix * ModelMatrix;
```

The name you chose 'ModelMatrix' may be confused with the matrix used to set objects in world space, not relative to camera. So better rename it:

```
glm::mat4 BulletInCameraMatrix = BulletTranslationMatrix * BulletRotationMatrix * BulletScaleMatrix;
glm::mat4 CameraAndProj = ProjectionMatrix * BulletInCameraMatrix ;
```

We can say that a point of the bullet xyz in bullet local coordinates get transformed into camera space as

```
glm::vec4 bulletViewCoords = CameraAndProj * glm::vec4(x, y, z, 1.0);
```

The rest of the objects suffer the transformation from their local space to camera (view) space by a matrix `VM = View * Model`. Now we want a point of the bullet in world space. So only undo the CameraAndProj and view transformations:

```
glm::mat4 BulletToWorld = glm::_inverse(CameraAndProj * View);
//bullet coordinates in world space
glm::vec4 bulletWorldCoords = BulletToWorld * glm::vec4(x, y, z, 1.0);
```

Notice that undoing step by step is `inv(CameraAndProj)` and then `inv(View)`. Matrix algebra tells us that it's equal to `inv(CameraAndProj * View)`

Comment: That makes sense, how can I get a glm::vec3 of world coordinates from the " inverse of the "View * Model" matrix" mat4 though?

Comment: glm provides inverse function. Get it. Multiply by (bullet_camera.x, bullet_camera.y, bullet_camera.z, 1.0). Get the .xyz part. That's it.

Comment: Not quite sure that I'm understanding the whole thing. My camera has a position vector, and horizontal/vertical angle floats. Can you please edit your post with code that would update my bulletPosition vector given the code I've provided? Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the update, that seems really useful. What exactly should x, y and z be in the bulletWorldCoords step though? Just my camera (player) position?

Comment: I did write it: "a point of the bullet xyz in **bullet local coordinates**"

Comment: You did, sorry. I'm just not clear on what that means for my code since each bullet model that's created doesn't have local coordinates yet(?)

Comment: Every object has local coordinates, for example being the origin at its centre, or at some corner of it. Your bullet is not a point, but a volume, right? How is every point in that volume defined?

Comment: Well my bullet model gets read in as a list of indices, which I then pass to VBOs. The code I posted is the only place where any kind of position is given to the bullet (which is just an offset so that the bullet appears at the right point in camera space), which is why I'm a bit unsure about local coordinates.

Comment: ...indices to vertices. Vertices defined in some space.